# How to access nested objects from my API and parsing the output in each loop to elements

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm currently updating my Website to use my new API, but i'm stuck with accessing the nested objects in a each loop. I don't know how to describe this anymore, cause i'm new to this whole ajax json type of stuff. Maybe if you look at my API Output and the JS i've come up with, you will see what i mean.

This is my code that did not really work...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.reyfm.de/v3/channel-sequence",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        rfm.log('Erfolgreich geladen.');
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            //COVER
            rfm.log('Coverart CHN' + key + ': ' + value);;
            $("#channel-" + key + " .cover").attr("src", (value));
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        log('Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: API nicht verfügbar.');
    }
});
```

This is the my API where i want to load the data from: https://api.reyfm.de/v3/channel-sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. Change it from:

```
.each(data, function(key, value) {
```

to:

```
$.each(data.channels, function(key, value) {
```

Another mistake is the space in the selector:

```
$("#channel-" + key + " .cover")
                       ^
```

In any case, when you select by id you do not need any other attribute. It's enough:

```
$("#channel-" + key)
```

Your last issue is how you access the element url:

```
value.coverurl
```

instead of:

```
(value)
```

Your loop is now:

```
$.each(data.channels, function(key, value) {
    $("#channel-" + key).attr("src", value.coverurl);
});
```

```js
var data = {
    "all-listeners": "235",
    "channels": {
        "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "original",
            "listeners": "128",
            "artist": "KHALID, 6LACK, TY DOLLA $IGN",
            "title": "OTW",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/khalid6lacktydollaign_otw.jpg"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "nightlife",
            "listeners": "7",
            "artist": "LUCA DEBONAIRE",
            "title": "STRANGERS",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/lucadebonaire_strangers.jpg"
        },
        "3": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "raproyal",
            "listeners": "27",
            "artist": "GRINGO, NIMO",
            "title": "BLUE LAGOON",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/gringonimo_bluelagoon.jpg"
        },
        "4": {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "underground",
            "listeners": "1",
            "artist": "KODAK BLACK",
            "title": "TUNNEL VISION",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/kodakblack_tunnelvision.jpg"
        },
        "5": {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "hitsonly",
            "listeners": "16",
            "artist": "BEBE REXHA",
            "title": "I'M A MESS",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/beberexha_imamess.jpg"
        },
        "6": {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "gaming",
            "listeners": "15",
            "artist": "ZEDD & MAREN MORRIS",
            "title": "THE MIDDLE",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/zeddmarenmorris_themiddle.jpg"
        },
        "7": {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "houseparty",
            "listeners": "2",
            "artist": "MURAT SEKER",
            "title": "WOLKE 10 (MURAT SEKER REMIX)",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/muratseker_wolke10muratseker_remix.jpg"
        },
        "8": {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "chillout",
            "listeners": "10",
            "artist": "LUKAS GRAHAM",
            "title": "LOVE SOMEONE",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/lukasgraham_lovesomeone.jpg"
        },
        "9": {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "exclusive",
            "listeners": "4",
            "artist": "LIKA MORGAN",
            "title": "IN MOTION",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/likamorgan_inmotion.jpg"
        },
        "10": {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "dancehall",
            "listeners": "2",
            "artist": "SQUASH",
            "title": "ALLERGY",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/squash_allergy.jpg"
        },
        "11": {
            "id": "11",
            "name": "summerjam",
            "listeners": "7",
            "artist": "MAJOR LAZER",
            "title": "RUN UP (FEAT. PARTYNEXTDOOR & NICKI MINAJ)",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/majorlazer_runup.jpg"
        },
        "12": {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "oldschool",
            "listeners": "2",
            "artist": "KID CUDI, MGMT, RATATAT",
            "title": "PURSUIT OF HAPPINESS",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/kidcudimgmtratatat_pursuitofhappiness.jpg"
        },
        "13": {
            "id": "13",
            "name": "mashup",
            "listeners": "4",
            "artist": "DJ LICIOUS",
            "title": "I HEAR YOU CALLING (ZONDERLING REMIX)",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/djlicious_ihearyoucallingzonderling_remix.jpg"
        },
        "14": {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "charts",
            "listeners": "10",
            "artist": "RUDIMENTAL",
            "title": "THESE DAYS (FEAT. JESS GLYNNE, MACKLEMORE & DAN CAPLEN)",
            "coverurl": "https:\/\/cdn.reyfm.de\/coverbilder\/rudimental_thesedays.jpg"
        }
    }
}
$.each(data.channels, function(key, value) {
    $("#channel-" + key).attr("href", value.coverurl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a id="channel-1" class="cover">channel-1</a>
<a id="channel-2" class="cover">channel-2</a>
<a id="channel-3" class="cover">channel-3</a>
<a id="channel-4" class="cover">channel-4</a>
<a id="channel-5" class="cover">channel-5</a>
<a id="channel-6" class="cover">channel-6</a>
<a id="channel-7" class="cover">channel-7</a>
<a id="channel-8" class="cover">channel-8</a>
<a id="channel-9" class="cover">channel-9</a>
<a id="channel-10" class="cover">channel-10</a>
<a id="channel-11" class="cover">channel-11</a>
<a id="channel-12" class="cover">channel-12</a>
<a id="channel-13" class="cover">channel-13</a>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for taking the time to help me! :)